# react-quill How to do undo & redo on button click?

Tags: reactjs, quill

I've tried by acquiring the quill object like this:

- got the ref from ReactQuill Component 
  `<ReactQuill ref={this.setRef}/>`
- and then in `componentDidMount` got the quill object itself 
  `this.quillRef= this.reactQuillRef.getEditor();`
- and then I call `this.quillRef.history.undo()` /  `this.quillRef.history.redo()`

But there seems to be a problem with focus, kinda like ReactQuill and Quill are out of sync. When i do undo or redo sometimes it just moves the cursor.

But everything works fine on `ctrl + z` and `ctrl + y`.